# Delete an image on java server

Tags: java

I am doing a project that consists of a java server and a web page. I'd like to do that when you delete an object from the web, the server deletes the image asociated with this object. The images of each object are stored inside the images folder inside the web folder. But when i try to delete an image in the server, it says that the file is used by another process,because the thread of the web server is using it (i use grizzly), so I an't delete it.

```
//save the image
private void saveImage(Eetakemon e){
    String base64Image = e.getImage().split(",")[1];
    byte[] imageBytes = 
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
    File imageFile = new File("WEB\\images\\" + e.getName() + ".png");
    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", imageFile);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//delete the image
private void deleteImage(Eetakemon e){
    try {
        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("WEB\\images\\" + e.getName() + 
".png"));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The funcions are called inside the create and delete methods respectively

Thank you

Comment: We will need much more details. I guess that the server is running on Windows, which does not allow to delete a file in use: you probably forgot to close a reader or writer... But it's difficult to offer more than vague hints. Can you share the bits of code where you deal with that file ? (Not just where you delete it)

Comment: Yes, I am using windows. The problem seems that the web server's thread has the images locked, and i can't delete them, but i don't know if there is any other alternative.

Comment: In the 2 methods you shared (one that *writes*, one that *deletes*), I don't see anything that can leave the file open (`ImageIO.write` should close the file when done), so the problem is probably not there. Don't you have another piece of your code somewhere that *reads* the file? -- Also you wrote *"it says that the file is used by another process"* : could you share exact error message, and stack trace if any?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a separate folder in your filesystem with read/write access  and keep your web server responsible for serving only static content, like static images, HTML,CSS and JS files.

To handle dynamic image files that can eventually be deleted during runtime keep the business logic in a separate service such as a REST API or a simple Servlet.

You can temporarily move the deleted images to a separate folder to be marked for deletion by a later scheduled batch job.

example of a service to delete an image:

```
public void removeFiles(List<String> fileNames) {
    try {
        String trashFolderLocation = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getConfig().getImgFileTrashPath();
        String uploadedFileLocation = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getConfig().getFilePath();

        FileUtil.moveFilesToFolder(uploadedFileLocation, trashFolderLocation, fileNames);       

    } catch(FileException e) {
        logException(e);
    }       
}
```

In FileUtil:

```
public static boolean moveFilesToFolder(String locationFrom, String locationTo, List<String> fileNames) throws FileException {
    try {
        for (String fileName : fileNames) {
            File afile = new File(locationFrom + fileName);
            if (!afile.renameTo(new File(locationTo + fileName))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FileException(e);
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good advice in there, but for better examples you could use newer [NIO.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/nio-139333.html) API from Java 7 like [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html), which provides better options & better error handling.

Comment: definitely better using your suggestion with Files NIO class

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a windows property of locking files that are used. You need to locate the process that are using the file and close the resource. This is your only viable option unless you are able to run on a system that doesn't lock files in use. Linux/Unix systems doesn't have this behaviour and they would allow you to delete the file even if it used.